# How to set a cookie with jquery

Tags: jquery, cookies

I have a *button*, *by clicking* on it *should be create a cookie*. I've tried to get it with jquery, and it's look like this:

**HTML:**

```
<a id="link" data-value="1">my link</a>
```

**jQuery:**

```
$('#link').click(function() {
    var value = $(this).attr('data-value');
    $.cookie('cookie', value);
});
```

So, it doesn't work. I have such type error: "**Uncaught TypeError: undefined is not a function** ".

Have you any propositions?

Comment: Did you include the cookie plugin? https://github.com/carhartl/jquery-cookie